# Pausar/retomar um Slideshow de Divs em Javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

fiz um slideshow de divs HTML para um projeto pessoal meu, vi no W3School como fazer e funciona, contudo, surgiu a necessidade de pausar esse slideshow com um botão dentro de cada div e depois poder retomar o slideshow de onde ele parou.

Usei esse exemplo por usar Divs ao invés do Bootstrap.

Tentei implementar uma lógica com variaveis globais para controlar o slideshow, porem sem sucesso.

Segue código:

```
<script>
    var pausa = false;
    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("publica");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        if(pausa){
            return;
        } else{
            setTimeout(carousel, 7000); 
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- divs que vão rodar em slideshow-->
<div class="publica">
    <div class="titulo">
        <p>Texto genérico</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="texto">
        <span>
        <p>Texto genérico</p>
    </div>              
    <hr>
    <div class="rodape">
        <button onclick="javascript:pausa=true;">Pausar</button>
        <button>Retomar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="publica">
    <div class="titulo">
        <p>Texto genérico</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="texto">
        <span>
        <p>Texto genérico</p>
    </div>              
    <hr>
    <div class="rodape">
        <button onclick="javascript:pausa=true;">Pausar</button>
        <button>Retomar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="publica">
    <div class="titulo">
        <p>Texto genérico</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="texto">
        <span>
        <p>Texto genérico</p>
    </div>              
    <hr>
    <div class="rodape">
        <button onclick="javascript:pausa=true;">Pausar</button>
        <button>Retomar</button>
    </div>
</div>
 <!-- script para iniciar a função de slideshow -->
<script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    carousel();
</script>
```

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando uma flag fora da função e alterando de setTimeout() para setInterval(), segue código para ajudar quem também tiver essa dúvida um dia:

```
<script>
    var isPaused = false;
    function carousel() {
        if(isPaused){
            return; 
        }
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("publica");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > x.length) {
            slideIndex = 1;
        }
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
    function pararSlide(element){
        console.log(isPaused);
        if(isPaused){
            isPaused = false;
            element.innerText="Pausar";
        } else{
            element.innerText="Continuar";
            isPaused = true;
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- DIV'S COM OS CONTEUDOS QUE ROTACIONARÃO, IGUAL O DE CIMA-->
<script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    carousel();
    setInterval(carousel, 7000);
</script>
```